# subscription not visible

Tags: azure, subscription, portal

We have purchased one Pay-As-You-Go subscription that was not visible in azure old portal (management portal) 
but its visible in new portal!

I have given the contributer role

Please let me know how I can add in old management portal

Thank,
Nihal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access old management portal, you need to be added as a co-administrator there. A `Contributor` role is specific to Azure's `Role-based access control (RBAC)` and only new portal is aware of them. Old portal doesn't know anything about RBAC and only users added as administrators (administrators, co-administrator, service administrator etc.) can access old portal.

Please ask your account administrator to add you as a co-administrator. Please see this link for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator/.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I have given owner permission its successfully changed from contributor to owner in new portal but still subscription is not visible in old management portal. Even for my administrator is the same he also can't see new subscription in management portal. Kindly give your feedback soon.

Comment: Please have the person who created the subscription (i.e. account administrator) login into old management portal and add you as a co-administrator there. Assigning owner role in the new portal won't work.

Comment: Gaurav, my administrator he was also not able to see new PAYG subscription in old portal?  so, he couldn't make me co-administrator. Kindly help me

Comment: Hmmm....That's totally weird. I would recommend reaching out to Azure Support. You can create a new support request from new portal itself.

Comment: Okay Gaurav I am contacting support and comeback to you with the reason..